# link button print wrongly because of beanclass tag

Tags: java, jsp, printing, prefix

Good day,

The following is my jsp code:

```
<sx:row key="com.ui.batchRefNo">
    <s:link beanclass="com.ui.Batches" event="detail" addSourcePage="true">
        ${paymentHistory.batchRefNo }
    </s:link>
</sx:row>

<sx:input name="print" image="buttons.print" cssClass="btn-primary" onclick="framePrint('mainFrame');return false" simple="true"/>
```

The following is my output after I click on print button:

[image]

Suppose it should only display
`File Batch Ref No  20140814AP007`, the rest of word inside the bracket is because of `beanClass`.

I already try make a division with `style="display:none;"` and put the link inside this division, but still same out put.

Kindly advise.

Comment: The Mainframe tag isn't what you think it is. Removing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as follow:

```
@media print {
    .noprint {display:none !important;}
    a:link:after, a:visited:after {  
      display: none;
      content: "";    
    }
}
```